# Is screen in the Kivy docs barely documented?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have a problem with the documentation kivy offers.
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.screen.html

There is no real documentation given on what methods the class inherits. For example, I can call #add_widget, but in the docs the method is not given / documented at all.

Hope someone can clarify me.

Ty for reading :)

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is any help in the module itself? `import kivy.modules.screen` `help(kivy.modules.screen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is to the `kivy.modules.screen` documentation, but this isn't something you'd use in your code - per the documentation, it's a module you'd enable when running Python, and there isn't much more to it than explained there.

It sounds like you're interested in the `kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen` class, so you want the `kivy.uix.screenmanager` docs, which you can find [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen), including the list of methods of Screen. This lists only the methods of Screen specifically, not its base classes, but there is a link `Bases: kivy.uix.relativelayout.RelativeLayout` to the class that it inherits from. By following these links, you can see all the base widgets and their methods.

Since all widgets inherit from `kivy.uix.widget.Widget`, methods like `add_widget` are always available.

Comment: I use Screen in my code all the time.  But since Screens are always managed by a ScreenManager that docs page should probably link to https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html?highlight=screenmanager#module-kivy.uix.screenmanager